# Holding data in custom attributes of Ruby core class (Programming style suggestion)

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Stumbled on this while writing a Ruby method to *generate permutations of a string of non-repeating characters*:

```
class String

  def permutations
    @result_array = []
    recurse( "", self.each_char.to_a )
    @result_array
  end

  def recurse( prepend_character, sub_array )
    sub_array.each{ |c|
      recurse( prepend_character + c, sub_array - [c] )
    }
    @result_array << prepend_character if sub_array.empty?
  end

end


p "abc".permutations # prints: ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```

Was thinking whether its appropriate or recommended to make an attribute inside a core class and hold data. Are there any ideas to avoid making an attribute to achieve this (without using a global variable)?

Comment: In general, it's not necessarily bad to add an attribute if you're opening up existing code, but in this case it isn't necessary.  You should be able to write a recursive function that actually returns a result; look into using `inject` instead of `each`.

Comment: @JacobM I was trying to rewrite it with inject; somehow just couldn't, may I don't enough to translate it to inject. Can you suggest any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring improvements that can be made to your logic, here is how you would rewrite it without adding unnecessary instance variables or functions to the class:

```
class String
    def permutations
        result = []
        recurse = lambda do |pre, sub|
            sub.each { |c| recurse[pre + c, sub - [c]] }
            result << pre if sub.empty?
        end
        recurse['', each_char.to_a]
        result
    end
end

'abc'.permutations
```

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't know that lambda's can be used like that! Thanks a lot, I was confused about how it scopes till I saw this code. Its after all code that can be considered in the same scope its defined in, just that its enclosed and has a name so that it can be invoked!

Out of curiosity, can you explain how to improve the code I shared, it seems I am missing something obvious? (Note: I am newbie to Ruby, so please excuse if its too silly code)

Comment: If your goal is to create a permutation algorithm then your code is fine. If you just want to permute something then don't reinvent the wheel: use Ruby's built-in methods as in phoet's answer.

Comment: Yes, my intention was just to create permutation algorithm. Performance and elegance is something I value dearly, so was pondering whether there is something I am overlooking through this implementation which I can improve it. Anyways, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know your tools, you should not change core classes. That should only be done by people knowing exactly what is going on.

So my advise: Don't do it until you really have to.

There are solutions for nearly everything in core Ruby:

```
"abc".split('').permutation.map(&:join)
=> ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba"]
```